# What are the main approaches on how to count inequality?

Tags: ethics, society

For the moment let's ignore distribution models like meritocracy.  Suppose a group has decided to divide their money in a certain way.  What are the different formulas to measure how even or equal their division is, (irrespective of their personal needs, efforts, etc.), strictly mathematically speaking?

For instance, we could calculate an *"index of inequality"* as:

- the sum of all the differences in the incomes of people,
- Or  as the sum of all differences from the average.
- Or from the median.

In short, there are many ways such an index might be defined, which affects how big a priority it is for the group.  What are the main approaches of measuring the rate of equality of allocation of resources in general?

Comment: "Strictly matyematically" makes no sense .... Divide the total amount of money for the number of people.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You're right, I'll edit it,m I jusat wanted to express I'm asking for the theories that are, indeed, subjective models of equality but models still possible to describe mathematically.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But there's one more important thing you might miss: It's not about total equality but the degrere of equality. Of course, total equality is when everybody gets the average. Though, it's not so clear for example if you compare one situation where there are three equal groups, one with 1$, one with 2$ and one with 3$ and when you compare the situation when most people get 2$, a little people get 0$ and a few people get 4$.

Comment: I think you mean to ask "what mathematical models of equality are there", or maybe even "what mathematical models of social equality are there". Is that right? I think the question is a little clearer if posed that way.

Comment: @EliranH Yeah, thank you I've used the formulation I've been given when asking on [Politics](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/what-are-most-common-formulas-for-computing-inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a terribly unphilosophical answer informed rather by economics:

As purely mathematical and for wealth distribution only (as per OP) the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) and normally nothing else, really.

It is [the most popular inequality index](http://www.fao.org/docs/up/easypol/329/gini_index_040en.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The work of John Rawls is probably the major effort of the twentieth century in analyzing the questions of freedom and equality. I recommend *Justice as Fairness*. The book is not an easy read, but Rawls lays out his arguments in detail.

Comment: Do you mean Rawls' articles "[Justice As Fairness](https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/jbell/rawls1.pdf)" (1958) & "[Justice As Fairness: Political Not Metaphysical](http://philosophyfaculty.ucsd.edu/faculty/rarneson/Courses/RawlsJustice.pdf)" (1985), or perhaps his books "[A Theory Of Justice](http://www.consiglio.regione.campania.it/cms/CM_PORTALE_CRC/servlet/Docs?dir=docs_biblio&file=BiblioContenuto_3641.pdf)" or specifically the recent "[Justice As Fairness: A Restatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_as_Fairness:_A_Restatement)"?

Comment: "Justice as Fairness: A Restatement" (Belknap Press 2001) (Erin Kelly, ed.)